# JK Flip-flop using D Flip-flop and gate level simulation does not stop

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, flip-flop

I'm trying to implement a JK flip-flop with a D flip-flop and a gate level, but the problem is that when I run the code, the terminal doesn't show me anything.  It's like it has always been calculating but nothing is shown.  I need to press `crtl + c` to stop the process, and this is when cmd shows something, but it is not the complete result.  I attached my code and images of the cmd.

```
module D_flip_flop (input  D,clk,Reset,enable,output reg F);
    always @(*) 
    begin
        if (Reset)
                F<='b0;
        else if (enable && clk) 
            F<=D;
    end 
endmodule
module JK_flip_flop(input J,K,clk,Reset,enable,output Q);
    wire S1,S2,S3,S4,S5;
    D_flip_flop D1(S4,clk,Reset,enable,Q);
    not N2(S5,Q);
    and A1(S1,J,S5);
    not N1(S3,K);
    and A2(S2,S3,Q);
    or O1(S4,S1,S2);

endmodule
```

testbench:

```
module testbench();

reg clk,reset,enable,J,K;
wire Q;
JK_flip_flop J1(J,K,clk,reset,enable,Q);
initial begin
    $display("\n");
    $display("Flip Flop JK");
    $display("J K clk Reset Enable | Q ");
    $display("----------------|---");
    $monitor("%b  %b %b %b %b | %b", J,K,clk,reset,enable,Q);
    J=0;K=0;reset=1;enable=0;clk=0;
    #1 reset=0;enable=1;
    #10 J=0;K=1;
    #10 J=1;K=0;
    #10 J=0;K=1;
    #10 J=1;K=1;
    #10 J=0;K=0;
    #50 $finish;
end
always
        begin
            #5 clk =~clk;
        end
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("Ej3_tb.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, testbench);
end

endmodule
```

Terminal before top the process:
[image]

Terminal after stop Process:
[image]

The JK flip-flop i'm trying to implement:

[image]

I don't know why this happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an incorrect way to model a DFF in Verilog.  This is the recommended way, triggering off the rising edge of the clock:

```
module D_flip_flop (input D,clk,Reset,enable, output reg F);
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (Reset)
            F <= 1'b0;
        else if (enable) 
            F <= D;
    end 
endmodule
```

The above code uses a synchronous reset.

This change allows the simulation to terminate cleanly (without a `Ctrl-C`).